# Show sheet number in LaTeX

Tags: page-numbering, counters

I want to show the sheet number instead page number in the header of odd pages, but it always shows 1:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newcounter{sheet}
\renewcommand*{\thesheet}{\arabic{sheet}}
\setcounter{sheet}{(\thepage+1)/2}

\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{
    \sethead
    [][][] % even
    {}{Sheet \thesheet}{} % odd
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

    First page
    \clearpage
    Second page
    \clearpage
    Third page

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

PS: It is important not to modify the `\thepage` counter to avoid conflicts with other packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `sheet` counter is never incremented with the `page` counter. Moreover, `\thepage` could be defined as something other than `\arabic{page}` and therefore not be a number (use `\value{page}` in calculations). Regardless, just set the sheet calculation directly in the header via `\numexpr`:

```
\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{
  \sethead
  [][][] % even
  {}{Sheet \number\numexpr(\value{page}+1)/2\relax}{} % odd
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!